# NAV2 and slam toolbox without prior map

Tags: slam, ros-humble, nav2

**First Represents my simple custom gazebo world**

[image]

**Second image shows rviz and NAV2 terminal output(Right top), slam Toolbox(Left bottom) launched in empty world**
[image]

**The third image represents launched NAV2(top right in terminal) and async_slam_toolbox with mapping mode, without prior map of gazebo world**
[image]

I am trying to setup NAV2 for physical robot but want to test the setup in simulation first. What I want is to use slam_toolbox without prior map and do navigation.

Issues I am facing is when I set NAV2Goal , robot is standing still. When I send the goal within the local costmap range it starts to navigate but not with long goals/ in case of global costmap.

The other thing which i think is wrong is when I see the transforms in rviz the odom frame should coincide the base_link at initial startup.However, the odom frame coincides with the map frame and is ahead of the base_link.
To verify this thing, I ran the whole stack with AMCL enabled, then the odom frame coincides with base_link at initial startup and also slam toolbox in pure localization mode does the same with prior map. But when I launch `online_async_slam` with mapping mode and the robot world is same for which I was having the map, this time it fails to do so. (tried with empty world also, same the stack crashes)

The terminal output

`[planner_server]: GridBased: failed to create plan, invalid use: Starting point in lethal space! Cannot create feasible plan. planner_server-2] [WARN] [1700588297.287430276] [nav2_costmap_2d]: Robot is out of bounds of the costmap! [planner_server-2] [WARN] [1700588297.287468315] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Sensor origin at (-0.34, 0.00) is out of map bounds (-0.34, 0.00) to (214748367.63, 214748367.97). The costmap cannot raytrace for it.`

**My NAV2 Params for costmaps**

```
`local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  use_sim_time: False
  rolling_window: true
  width: 5
  height: 5
  resolution: 0.25
  footprint: "[[-0.6, 0.285475], [-0.6, -0.285475], [0.6, 0.285475], [0.6, -0.285475]]"
  #robot_radius: 0.5
  plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
  inflation_layer:
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
    cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
    inflation_radius: 0.55
  obstacle_layer:
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
    enabled: True
    observation_sources: scan
    scan:
      topic: /scan
      max_obstacle_height: 3.0
      clearing: True
      marking: True
      data_type: "LaserScan"
      raytrace_max_range: 6.0
      raytrace_min_range: 0.0
      obstacle_max_range: 6.0 #1.0
      obstacle_min_range: 0.0
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True
  always_send_full_costmap: True
 local_costmap_client:
   ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
     ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False`
```

**Global costmap**

```
`global_costmap:
    global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  use_sim_time: false
  footprint: "[[-0.6, 0.285475], [-0.6, -0.285475], [0.6, 0.285475], [0.6, -0.285475]]"
  #robot_radius: 0.5
  resolution: 0.25 #0.05
  track_unknown_space: true
  unknown_cost_value: 120
  plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
  obstacle_layer:
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
    enabled: True
    observation_sources: scan
    scan:
      topic: /scan
      max_obstacle_height: 3.0
      clearing: True
      marking: True
      data_type: "LaserScan"
      raytrace_max_range: 6.0
      raytrace_min_range: 0.0
      obstacle_max_range: 6.0 #1.0
      obstacle_min_range: 0.0
  static_layer:
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True
  inflation_layer:
    plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
    cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
    inflation_radius: 0.55
  always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
   ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False`
```

I have tried to tweaking with costmap params but no luck. Could anybody advice something to deal with this issue or is my approach is right to do SLAM with NAV2 and no prior map?

When I try to launch the whole stack in empty world, and give NAV2Goal the stack crashes.But that is what I want the it should map the environment while localizing, isn't that slam_toolbox supposed to do? I am bit new to this, so any guidance will be appreciated. @StevenMackenski

Comment: Can you shown an image in rviz of when that error occurs?

Comment: I have added the images to original post as asked. Just to mention the slam-toolbox terminal log doesn't show errors in either case.@SteveMacenski

Comment: I obsereved something strange. After giving goal within local map area it starts to follow NAV2GOAL and then if I send long goals it seems its planning global path and following it. The blue line represents the global plan. One thing, the odom frame is not moving with base_link, I don't know why this is happening?This is the link to the gif.https://universityoflincoln-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/27339244_students_lincoln_ac_uk/EYU9sh2JiBRFvHJqP191AUEBUz9Q5k5UyrL77X31-E1zOw?e=6FvPm8

Comment: What planner / control algorithms? Your lack of coverage of sensor ranges are notable, you should have more sensors that cover than a couple of meters.

Comment: I am using DWB controller and Smac planner hybrid. I have only one sensor available for real robot (intel realsense depth cam))

Comment: This is a lidar based package, use a depth camera SLAM if you want to use a realsense camera

Comment: I tried with Cartographer and deployed the whole stack on the real robot, it is running NAV2 but not planning the path. 

Output is Planner Server: starting point in lethal space. 
And NAV2 immediately switches to behaviour server which makes sense and I can see the spin wait and backup.